# Selenium in Python: find element after a click

Tags: python, selenium

I need to build a find and click procedure, step by step, but I'm not able to do it.

My starting code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)#seconds 
driver.get('http://mywebpage.com/page')
# The browser open page1

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
confirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='button_serv'])[4]")))
confirm.click()
# The browser open page2 in the same window
```

Now I would like to find an element in page2, but the driver points always to page1 (because my code is wrong):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
confirm = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='button_serv'])[9]")))
confirm.click()
```

How to tell to selenium to wait and search fon content of page2?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the second page to load (assuming it is loaded by the `confirm.click()`). There are multiple ways you can do it. One of which is to *wait for the URL to change* checking the `driver.current_url` value inside the `wait.until()`:

```
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != "http://mywebpage.com/page")
```

You can also wait for the ["staleness"](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of) of the first "confirm" element:

> Wait until an element is no longer attached to the DOM. element is the element to wait for. returns False if the element is still attached to the DOM, true otherwise.

```
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(confirm))
```

Note that there is no need to re-instantiate `WebDriverWait()` multiple times - do it once, after you define your `driver` instance.

Comment: Hi alecxe, thank you. The URL is always the same, it's an horrible website with cookie and session without permalinks. After the load of page2 I must find an element (and than click on it)

Comment: @aborruso ah, then the "staleness of" approach might work for you, give it a try. Thanks.